# Webpack imported variable undefined unless I assign it to another variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import

This works:

```js
import register from './ComponentsRegister';

const register_ = register; // Hacky
const Components = {}

for (var i=0; i<register_.length; i++) {
  Components[register_[i].name] = require(''+register_[i].path).default;
}

export default Components;
```

But this doesn't:

```js
import register_ from './ComponentsRegister';

// const register_ = register; // Hacky
const Components = {}

for (var i=0; i<register_.length; i++) {
  Components[register_[i].name] = require(''+register_[i].path).default;
}

export default Components;
```

Error: `ReferenceError: register_ is not defined`. For reference, this is what ComponentsRegister.js looks like:

```js
const register = [
  {
    name: 'About',
    path: './components/About'
  },
  {
    name: 'Footer',
    path: './components/Footer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Header',
    path: './components/Header'
  },
  {
    name: 'Home',
    path: './components/Home'
  }
];

export default register;
```

It's just an array of objects with 2 properties: name and path. I'm creating this as a way to dynamically import components.